# Does anyone know how to lock the screen using monkeyrunner?

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I am trying to lock the screen using monkeyrunner.
Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Using python we can use def isScreenOn(self): to validate whether the backlight is ON/OFF ...  def isScreenOn(self): will return TRUE if Screen is "ON"..                                                          Check:https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/src/com/dtmilano/android/adb/adbclient.py

Answer (score 1):

try below code:-

```
device.press('KEYCODE_POWER',MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
```

Answer (score 0):

press power button of emulator using monkeyRunner, and press